# How do I use MUpdf in an existing java project

Tags: java, pdf, mupdf

Mupdf documentation shows me how to use the library as an application and deploy it. However, I want to suck it into an existing java project and build my application on top of it.  Can this be done?  If so, how do I bring just the pieces needed, into my project?

Comment: Duplicate at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19478168/android-pdf-viewer-library-or-mupdf-library-tutorials (which is later but has more discussion within it)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at [jMuPdf](http://jmupdf.sourceforge.net/joomla/). I never used it, but it seems to be active.

Otherwise you will need to create Java Native Bindings (JNA or JNI).

Comment: I knew the part about JNI, but I hadn't seen jMUPDF. I'll check that out. Thanks!